# GMP library usage cause memory exhaustion

Tags: c, cryptography, pthreads, out-of-memory, gmp

I am using GMP library for large number of calculation. I have checked through valgrind that there is no memory leaks in program for small numbers of calculations. But when I try to calculate large number of calculations like for 124 bits, then it exhausts all my machine memory and ultimately OS need to kill the process.

Any help how can I make memory consumption stable using GMP library will be highly appreciated.

```
ThreadArgs* pThreadArgs = (ThreadArgs*)pArgs;
    
    //gmp_printf("Inside worker thread %Zd\n", pThreadArgs->i);
    struct Point output;
        mpz_init_set_ui(output.x, 0);
        mpz_init_set_ui(output.y, 0);
        
    // i * G    
    struct Point Q, T;
    long no_of_bits, loop;
    mpz_t slope, temp;
    mpz_t PA_temp,PA_slope;
    mpz_inits(slope, temp, PA_temp, PA_slope, NULL);
    mpz_init(Q.x);
    mpz_init(Q.y);
    mpz_init(T.x);
    mpz_init(T.y);
    
    no_of_bits = mpz_sizeinbase(pThreadArgs->i, 2);
    
    //printf("%s:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    if(mpz_cmp_ui(pThreadArgs->i, 0) != 0)  {
        mpz_set(Q.x, G.x);
        mpz_set(Q.y, G.y);
        if(mpz_tstbit(pThreadArgs->i, 0) == 1){
            mpz_set(output.x, G.x);
            mpz_set(output.y, G.y);
        }
        for(loop = 1; loop < no_of_bits; loop++) {
            //P, R
            //Point_Doubling(&Q, &T);
                mpz_set_si(temp, 0);
                mpz_set_si(slope, 0);
                if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) != 0) {
                        mpz_mul_ui(temp, Q.y, 2);
                        mpz_invert(temp, temp, EC.p);
                        mpz_mul(slope, Q.x, Q.x);
                        mpz_mul_ui(slope, slope, 3);
                        mpz_mul(slope, slope, temp);
                        mpz_mod(slope, slope, EC.p);
                        mpz_mul(T.x, slope, slope);
                        mpz_sub(T.x, T.x, Q.x);
                        mpz_sub(T.x, T.x, Q.x);
                        mpz_mod(T.x, T.x, EC.p);
                        mpz_sub(temp, Q.x, T.x);
                        mpz_mul(T.y, slope, temp);
                        mpz_sub(T.y, T.y, Q.y);
                        mpz_mod(T.y, T.y, EC.p);
                } else {
                        mpz_set_ui(T.x, 0);
                        mpz_set_ui(T.y, 0);
                }
            
            mpz_set(Q.x, T.x);
            mpz_set(Q.y, T.y);
            mpz_set(T.x, output.x);
            mpz_set(T.y, output.y);
            if(mpz_tstbit(pThreadArgs->i, loop)) {
                // P , Q, R
                //Point_Addition(&T, &Q, &output);
                    mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
                    mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(T.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(T.y, 0) == 0) {
                            mpz_set(output.x, Q.x);
                            mpz_set(output.y, Q.y);
                    }
                    else    {
                            if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) == 0) {
                                    mpz_set(output.x, T.x);
                                    mpz_set(output.y, T.y);
                            }
                            else    {
                                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) != 0) {
                                            mpz_sub(PA_temp, EC.p, Q.y);
                                            mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);
                                    }
                                    else    {
                                            mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
                                    }
                                    if(mpz_cmp(T.y, PA_temp) == 0 && mpz_cmp(T.x, Q.x) == 0) {
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.x, 0);
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.y, 0);
                                    }
                                    else    {
                                            if(mpz_cmp(T.x, Q.x) == 0 && mpz_cmp(T.y, Q.y) == 0) {
                                                    //P, R
                                //Point_Doubling(&T, &output);
                                    mpz_set_ui(temp, 0);
                                    mpz_set_ui(slope, 0);
                                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(T.y, 0) != 0) {
                                            mpz_mul_ui(temp, T.y, 2);
                                            mpz_invert(temp, temp, EC.p);
                                            mpz_mul(slope, T.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_mul_ui(slope, slope, 3);
                                            mpz_mul(slope, slope, temp);
                                            mpz_mod(slope, slope, EC.p);
                                            mpz_mul(output.x, slope, slope);
                                            mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_mod(output.x, output.x, EC.p);
                                            mpz_sub(temp, T.x, output.x);
                                            mpz_mul(output.y, slope, temp);
                                            mpz_sub(output.y, output.y, T.y);
                                            mpz_mod(output.y, output.y, EC.p);
                                    } else {
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.x, 0);
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.y, 0);
                                    }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
                                                    mpz_sub(PA_temp, T.x, Q.x);   //dx = B.x - A.x
                                mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);                ///dx = dx % p
                                                    mpz_invert(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);     //gmpy2.invert(dx, p) % p
                                                    mpz_sub(PA_slope, T.y, Q.y);
                                                    mpz_mul(PA_slope, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                                    mpz_mod(PA_slope, PA_slope, EC.p);
                                                    mpz_mul(output.x, PA_slope, PA_slope);      //c*c
                                                    mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);      //      c*c - A.x
                                                    mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, Q.x);      //(c*c - A.x) - B.x
                                                    mpz_mod(output.x, output.x, EC.p);      // Rx % p
                                                    mpz_sub(PA_temp, T.x, output.x);
                                                    mpz_mul(output.y, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                                    mpz_sub(output.y, output.y, T.y);
                                                    mpz_mod(output.y, output.y, EC.p);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    //gmp_printf("i*G: %Zd: %Zx, %Zx\n", pThreadArgs->i, output.x, output.y);
    // P = Q - i * G
        struct Point P;
        mpz_init(P.x);
        mpz_init(P.y);
    if(mpz_cmp_ui(output.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(output.y, 0) == 0)
        {
                mpz_set(P.x, QGlobal.x);
                mpz_set(P.y, QGlobal.y);
        }
    else
    {
            struct Point negateSubtractend;
            mpz_init(negateSubtractend.x);
            mpz_init(negateSubtractend.y);
        mpz_sub(negateSubtractend.y, EC.p, output.y);
            mpz_set(negateSubtractend.x, output.x);
        // P,Q, R
            //Point_Addition(&QGlobal, &negateSubtractend, &P);
        //mpz_t PA_temp,PA_slope;
            mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
            mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
            if(mpz_cmp_ui(QGlobal.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(QGlobal.y, 0) == 0) {
                    mpz_set(P.x, negateSubtractend.x);
                    mpz_set(P.y, negateSubtractend.y);
            }
            else    {
                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(negateSubtractend.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(negateSubtractend.y, 0) == 0) {
                            mpz_set(P.x, QGlobal.x);
                            mpz_set(P.y, QGlobal.y);
                    }
                    else    {
                            if(mpz_cmp_ui(negateSubtractend.y, 0) != 0) {
                                    mpz_sub(PA_temp, EC.p, negateSubtractend.y);
                                    mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);
                            }
                            else    {
                                    mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
                            }
                            if(mpz_cmp(QGlobal.y, PA_temp) == 0 && mpz_cmp(QGlobal.x, negateSubtractend.x) == 0) {
                                    mpz_set_ui(P.x, 0);
                                    mpz_set_ui(P.y, 0);
                            }
                            else    {
                                    if(mpz_cmp(QGlobal.x, negateSubtractend.x) == 0 && mpz_cmp(QGlobal.y, negateSubtractend.y) == 0)        {
                        // P, R
                                            //Point_Doubling(QGlobal, P);
                            mpz_set_ui(temp, 0);
                            mpz_set_ui(slope, 0);
                            if(mpz_cmp_ui(QGlobal.y, 0) != 0) {
                                    mpz_mul_ui(temp, QGlobal.y, 2);
                                    mpz_invert(temp, temp, EC.p);
                                    mpz_mul(slope, QGlobal.x, QGlobal.x);
                                    mpz_mul_ui(slope, slope, 3);
                                    mpz_mul(slope, slope, temp);
                                    mpz_mod(slope, slope, EC.p);
                                    mpz_mul(P.x, slope, slope);
                                    mpz_sub(P.x, P.x, QGlobal.x);
                                    mpz_sub(P.x, P.x, QGlobal.x);
                                    mpz_mod(P.x, P.x, EC.p);
                                    mpz_sub(temp, QGlobal.x, P.x);
                                    mpz_mul(P.y, slope, temp);
                                    mpz_sub(P.y, P.y, QGlobal.y);
                                    mpz_mod(P.y, P.y, EC.p);
                            } else {
                                    mpz_set_ui(P.x, 0);
                                    mpz_set_ui(P.y, 0);
                            }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                            mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
                                            mpz_sub(PA_temp, QGlobal.x, negateSubtractend.x);   //dx = B.x - A.x
                        mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);                ///dx = dx % p
                                            mpz_invert(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);     //gmpy2.invert(dx, p) % p
                                            mpz_sub(PA_slope, QGlobal.y, negateSubtractend.y);
                                            mpz_mul(PA_slope, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                            mpz_mod(PA_slope, PA_slope, EC.p);
                                            mpz_mul(P.x, PA_slope, PA_slope);      //c*c
                                            mpz_sub(P.x, P.x, QGlobal.x);      //      c*c - A.x
                                            mpz_sub(P.x, P.x, negateSubtractend.x);      //(c*c - A.x) - B.x
                                            mpz_mod(P.x, P.x, EC.p);      // Rx % p
                                            mpz_sub(PA_temp, QGlobal.x, P.x);
                                            mpz_mul(P.y, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                            mpz_sub(P.y, P.y, QGlobal.y);
                                            mpz_mod(P.y, P.y, EC.p);
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
            mpz_clears(negateSubtractend.x, negateSubtractend.y, NULL);
    }

    //gmp_printf("P = Q-i*G: %Zd: %Zx, %Zx\n", pThreadArgs->i, P.x, P.y);
        // k * P 
    // P, output, scalar
    //Point_Scalar_Multiplication(P, &output, k);
        mpz_set_ui(Q.x, 0);
        mpz_set_ui(Q.y, 0);
        mpz_set_ui(T.x, 0);
        mpz_set_ui(T.y, 0);
        no_of_bits = mpz_sizeinbase(k, 2);
        mpz_set_ui(output.x, 0);
        mpz_set_ui(output.y, 0);

        //printf("%s:%d\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
        if(mpz_cmp_ui(k, 0) != 0)  {
                mpz_set(Q.x, P.x);
                mpz_set(Q.y, P.y);
                if(mpz_tstbit(k, 0) == 1){
                        mpz_set(output.x, P.x);
                        mpz_set(output.y, P.y);
                }
                for(loop = 1; loop < no_of_bits; loop++) {
                        //Point_Doubling(&Q, &T);
            mpz_set_ui(temp, 0);
                        mpz_set_ui(slope, 0);
                        if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) != 0) {
                                mpz_mul_ui(temp, Q.y, 2);
                                mpz_invert(temp, temp, EC.p);
                                mpz_mul(slope, Q.x, Q.x);
                                mpz_mul_ui(slope, slope, 3);
                                mpz_mul(slope, slope, temp);
                                mpz_mod(slope, slope, EC.p);
                                mpz_mul(T.x, slope, slope);
                                mpz_sub(T.x, T.x, Q.x);
                                mpz_sub(T.x, T.x, Q.x);
                                mpz_mod(T.x, T.x, EC.p);
                                mpz_sub(temp, Q.x, T.x);
                                mpz_mul(T.y, slope, temp);
                                mpz_sub(T.y, T.y, Q.y);
                                mpz_mod(T.y, T.y, EC.p);
                        } else {
                                mpz_set_ui(T.x, 0);
                                mpz_set_ui(T.y, 0);
                        }

                        mpz_set(Q.x, T.x);
                        mpz_set(Q.y, T.y);
                        mpz_set(T.x, output.x);
                        mpz_set(T.y, output.y);
            if(mpz_tstbit(k, loop))
            {
                //P, Q, R
                                //Point_Addition(&T, &Q, &output);
                //mpz_t PA_temp,PA_slope;
                    mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
                    mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(T.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(T.y, 0) == 0) {
                            mpz_set(output.x, Q.x);
                            mpz_set(output.y, Q.y);
                    }
                    else    {
                            if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.x, 0) == 0 && mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) == 0) {
                                    mpz_set(output.x, T.x);
                                    mpz_set(output.y, T.y);
                            }
                            else    {
                                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(Q.y, 0) != 0) {
                                            mpz_sub(PA_temp, EC.p, Q.y);
                                            mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);
                                    }
                                    else    {
                                            mpz_set_ui(PA_temp, 0);
                                    }
                                    if(mpz_cmp(T.y, PA_temp) == 0 && mpz_cmp(T.x, Q.x) == 0) {
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.x, 0);
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.y, 0);
                                    }
                                    else    {
                                            if(mpz_cmp(T.x, Q.x) == 0 && mpz_cmp(T.y, Q.y) == 0)        {
                                                    //P, R
                                //Point_Doubling(&T, &output);
                                    mpz_set_ui(temp, 0);
                                    mpz_set_ui(slope, 0);
                                    if(mpz_cmp_ui(T.y, 0) != 0) {
                                            mpz_mul_ui(temp, T.y, 2);
                                            mpz_invert(temp, temp, EC.p);
                                            mpz_mul(slope, T.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_mul_ui(slope, slope, 3);
                                            mpz_mul(slope, slope, temp);
                                            mpz_mod(slope, slope, EC.p);
                                            mpz_mul(output.x, slope, slope);
                                            mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);
                                            mpz_mod(output.x, output.x, EC.p);
                                            mpz_sub(temp, T.x, output.x);
                                            mpz_mul(output.y, slope, temp);
                                            mpz_sub(output.y, output.y, T.y);
                                            mpz_mod(output.y, output.y, EC.p);
                                    } else {
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.x, 0);
                                            mpz_set_ui(output.y, 0);
                                    }
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                    mpz_set_ui(PA_slope, 0);
                                mpz_sub(PA_temp, T.x, Q.x);   //dx = B.x - A.x
                                                    mpz_mod(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);                ///dx = dx % p
                                                    mpz_invert(PA_temp, PA_temp, EC.p);     //gmpy2.invert(dx, p) % p
                                                    mpz_sub(PA_slope, T.y, Q.y);
                                                    mpz_mul(PA_slope, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                                    mpz_mod(PA_slope, PA_slope, EC.p);
                                                    mpz_mul(output.x, PA_slope, PA_slope);      //c*c
                                                    mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, T.x);      //      c*c - A.x
                                                    mpz_sub(output.x, output.x, Q.x);      //(c*c - A.x) - B.x
                                                    mpz_mod(output.x, output.x, EC.p);      // Rx % p
                                                    mpz_sub(PA_temp, T.x, output.x);
                                                    mpz_mul(output.y, PA_slope, PA_temp);
                                                    mpz_sub(output.y, output.y, T.y);
                                                    mpz_mod(output.y, output.y, EC.p);
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
                }
        }

    //gmp_printf("k*P: %Zd: %Zx, %Zx\n", pThreadArgs->i, output.x, output.y);
    char* pStrOutput = point2upub(&output);
        if(!strncmp(pThreadArgs->pPublicKey, pStrOutput, strlen(pStrOutput)) ||
       !strncmp(pThreadArgs->pPublicKeyLower, pStrOutput, strlen(pStrOutput)))
        {
               mpz_add_ui(pThreadArgs->i, pThreadArgs->i, 1U);
               gmp_printf("%Zd\n", pThreadArgs->i);
           exit(0);
        }
      
    free(pStrOutput);

        mpz_clears(output.x, output.y, NULL);
        mpz_clears(P.x, P.y, NULL);
    mpz_clears(pThreadArgs->i, temp, slope, PA_temp, PA_slope, NULL);
    mpz_clears(Q.x, Q.y, T.x, T.y, NULL);
```

This is actual code that runs 2^nbits times, where nbits = 124.

Comment: what is the value of `nBits`?

Comment: I provide nBits value 124.

Comment: I suspect you're running out of memory not because of a memory leak, but simply because you're trying to work on too big a problem, period!  2¹²⁴ is a fantastically big number.  You've got a loop there that's tantamount to `for(i = 0; i < 21267647932558653966460912964485513216; i++)`, I think, and even if you did have enough memory, that looks like it's going to take quiiiiiiiite a long time to run...

Comment: If you want a better (less speculative) answer, though, you're going to have to post a more complete code sample.  Besides `nBits`, we can't see what `Q`, `T`, and `EC` are.  (If I knew more about Elliptic Curve cryptography I might be able to guess, but we're not supposed to have to guess.)

Comment: What other values of `nBits` have you tried?  For which values does the program work properly?  For each value of `nBits` that you've tried, how long does the program take to run, and what is its memory usage?  How fast do those two numbers seem to be growing as a function of `nBits`?

Comment: what I observed, through custome allocator, that memory allocation rate is much faster then memory deallocation rate. I tried with nbits 20, then it was running fine and no memory leak. Q and T are temporary mpz_t variable and value of EC.P is fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffefffffc2f.

Comment: I don't see any indication that your code is leaking memory.  I can't explain why your custom allocator suggested a memory leak, because I haven't seen your custom allocator.  When I run the code, I don't see any indications of excessive memory usage. *However*, I can say with some confidence that the time it takes to run this code doubles for each increase in the value of `nBits`.  It may have run fast enough for `nBits = 20`, but I encourage you to try it for, say, 25, 26, and 27.

Comment: I have provided actual code of threadfunction, that runs within 8 threads. what I am observing high memory usage and it consume all memory. what I have seen memory allocator rate is higher than free memory.

Comment: I have used these custom allocator to check memory diff.

Comment: '''
void* malloc_func (size_t alloc_size)
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 static long allot_size = 0; 
 void* p = malloc(alloc_size);
 allot_size += alloc_size;
 if(p!= 0 || alloc_size == 0)
 {
  printf("malloc: total: %ld\n",  allot_size);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
  return p;
 }
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
 return NULL;
}

void free_func(void* p, size_t size) {
 pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
 static long memoryFree = 0; 
 memoryFree += size;
 free(p);
 printf("freemem: %ld\n", memoryFree);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
'''

Comment: These are custom allocator. I find with single bit iteration that there memory difference between allot and free size.

Comment: Where is `free_func` called?

Comment: free_func is called to free memory, in place of standard free function.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  I know what `free_func` *is*.  I asked where it was called.  There are no calls to it in the code that you posted.  Where, exactly, are the calls to `free_func` that occur instead of the standard `free` function?

Comment: Finally my problem got resolved. I was thinking error was at gmp side, that was not the case. I checked memory leak with every individual used gmp api there was no leak with that. GMP is good, there was error at my end due to multthreading. One of thread was consuming lot of memory, so I throttled that then problem got resolved. Thanks @Steve Summit for help.